# enum size option in VS 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, enums, size, sizeof

Can I set some options in Visual Studio 2010 to change **enum** size to **1 byte**? Code changes is prohibited. I need some compilation options.

Comment: I think you can't, talking about C. MS C enum are always int type.

Comment: Are you talking about the size of the representation of the `enum` type, or the size of the value of one of the associated enum constants?  These are not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: I am talking about size of enum constants. (sizeof(Color.RED))

Comment: I need something like typed enum in C++, but without code changes.

Comment: I have answered the question both ways.  Note that the size of the `enum` constants probably is *not* what you want to affect, because that has little observable consequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two logically different sizes you could be talking about: the size of the enum *constants* associated with a given enum type, or the size of an object whose own type is the enum type.  For example, given

```
enum example { ONE, TWO };
enum example enum_variable;
```

the first declaration declares both the type `enum example` and the constants `ONE` and `TWO`.

Perhaps surprisingly, the constants do *not* have type `enum example`; rather they have type `int`, and they will therefore consume whatever amount of space an `int` requires (C99 6.7.2.2/3).

On the other hand, `enum_variable` does have type `enum example`, and more likely it is actually the size of this type that you hope to affect.  C gives some constraints there, but designates the specific choice to be implementation-defined (C99 6.7.2.2/4). That's a bit hopeful because it requires implementations to in fact document their choice, and [the VS 2010 docs do so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17z041d4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you drill down far enough.  Unfortunately for you, the docs say that a variable of `enum` type is an `int`.  If the docs are to be believed, then, the size of `enum` variables is not adjustable in VS 2010.